# How do I configure emacs to stop adding an extra closing bracket when hitting space?

Tags: web-mode, prelude, ruby

I'm using `web-mode` to edit my `erb` files. When I type `<%` emacs (or `web-mode`) adds a closing `%>` bracket. But when I type a space *after* the percent sign (i.e. `%`), an additional `%>` bracket is added.

I'm using `prelude` so there's a clue in `prelude-web.el` but I'm not sure how to interpret it. The relevant looking code looks like this:

```
(sp-with-modes '(web-mode)                                                                                                           
  (sp-local-pair "%" "%"                                                                                                             
                 :unless '(sp-in-string-p)                                                                                           
                 :post-handlers '(((lambda (&rest _ignored)                                                                          
                                     (just-one-space)                                                                                
                                     (save-excursion (insert " ")))                                                                  
                                   "SPC" "=" "#")))                                                                                  
  (sp-local-pair "<% "  " %>" :insert "C-c %")                                                                                       
  (sp-local-pair "<%= " " %>" :insert "C-c =")                                                                                       
  (sp-local-pair "<%# " " %>" :insert "C-c #")                                                                                       
  (sp-local-tag "%" "<% "  " %>")                                                                                                    
  (sp-local-tag "=" "<%= " " %>")                                                                                                    
  (sp-local-tag "#" "<%# " " %>"))
```

How do I configure emacs to stop adding these additional characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. Hopefully it will get pulled into `prelude` main branch soon. You can edit the file cited above:

https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/pull/805